# Loading kml files into the google-earth-plugin on a web-hosted page

Tags: url, google-docs, google-earth-plugin

Try as I might, I seem unable to access kml files from an instance of the google-earth-plugin on my publicly-hosted web page. Using all the google developer help I can find and trying Fetchkml as well as kmlNetworkLink with no success, I have tried to approach the problem in a one-step-at-a-time way and reached the following impass:

Using the following javascript code *works* when I point to a kml source at code.google.com:

```
    google.load("earth", "1");
    var ge;
    function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance('mapthreedee', initCB, failureCB);
    }
    function initCB(instance) {
        ge = instance;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
        ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);

        var link = ge.createLink('');
        var href = 'http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example.kml';
        link.setHref(href);

        var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('');
        networkLink.set(link, true, true); // Sets the link, refreshVisibility, and flyToView

        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
 }
         function failureCB(errorCode) {
    alert("failure");
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);         
</script>
```

The google-earth plugin zooms down to San Fransisco. However, if I download this same kml_example.kml source file using google Chrome, place the untouched kml file into my google docs document space, get the relevant id address for it and paste this address into the javascript code on my web page (with no other changes to the code at all), like so:

```
    google.load("earth", "1");
    var ge;
    function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance('mapthreedee', initCB, failureCB);
    }
    function initCB(instance) {
        ge = instance;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
        ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);

        var link = ge.createLink('');
        var href = 'https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3kCsTNlhwBaM2I5YTk0ZjEtOGVlNS00MGU4LTk5MTgtYTUyYzQ2Mzc2Mzhl';
        link.setHref(href);

        var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('');
        networkLink.set(link, true, true); // Sets the link, refreshVisibility, and flyToView

        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
 }
         function failureCB(errorCode) {
    alert("failure");
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);         
</script></code>
```

No kml is accessed when the page loads, although the google-earth-plugin still loads correctly. I am only going to these extremes because a kmz location (in Norway) I have in google docs, which I can access perfectly well via Network Link in the google Earth client on my PC, does not appear in the google-earth-plugin when I try to access it using identical code to the above.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

These web pages are at http://geoffreychaucernm.co.uk/offlineTEST_SITE_ghp/googlemaps/googleEarth_3.html and http://geoffreychaucernm.co.uk/offlineTEST_SITE_ghp/googlemaps/googleEarth_4.html

The site is hosted on a 1and1 Microsoft web server.

Comment: That docs link doesn't work for me in Google Earth client. I'm actually curious how the KMZ file works. Do you have to sign in to Google Docs before you can access the file? Does the URL work directly?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to kick yourself.

All the code you have shown in your example is fine. The simple problem is the url you are using for the `kml_example.kml` source file located on your google docs account.

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3kCsTNlhwBaM2I5YTk0ZjEtOGVlNS00MGU4LTk5MTgtYTUyYzQ2Mzc2Mzhl

Notice this URL *redirects* to a download page, not to the actual kml file. You need to get a Uri for file itself not this intermediate page.

The easy fix is to replace the above url with this one and it should work

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3kCsTNlhwBaM2I5YTk0ZjEtOGVlNS00MGU4LTk5MTgtYTUyYzQ2Mzc2Mzhl&export=download

Notice this downloads the file (links directly).

Edit:

The slight change in URL and additional `export=download` parameter clearly

```
https://docs.google.com/open?id=FILE_ID

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID&export=download
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The adjustment to the google Docs query string you suggest works brilliantly. A thousand thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please mark the answer as accepted - people will be more likely to help you in the future if you do!